# Get unallocated slot count from INFORMATION_SCHEMA in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

There is currently a lot of information related to slot reservations.  With a number of queries provided by Google on analyzing slot usage.  I.E. from this [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-reservations) here:

```
WITH
  job_data AS (
  SELECT
    job.period_start,
    job.reservation_id,
    job.period_slot_ms,
    job.job_id,
    job.job_type
  FROM
    `my-project.region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT AS job
  WHERE
    job.period_start > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
SELECT
  reservation.reservation_name AS reservation_name,
  job.period_start,
  reservation.slot_capacity,

  -- !!! might include unallocated slots or slots from other res
  job.period_slot_ms,   

  job.job_id,
  job.job_type
FROM
  job_data AS job
INNER JOIN
  `reservation-admin-project.region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.RESERVATIONS_BY_PROJECT AS reservation
ON
  (job.reservation_id = CONCAT(reservation.project_id, ":", "US", ".", reservation.reservation_name));
```

The problem when trying to effectively model current reservations is that unallocated slots are not in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables... but ARE available for use by queries.  So usage always seems overallocated when doing ratios.

Is there a way to query how many unallocated slots my ADMIN project currently has to include in these ratios?  I can not find anything in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

See slot allocation screenshot below.  I want to be able to pull 2026 into my query as additional available resource.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best I have been able to come up with is taking the difference of the sum of the average of all allocations from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.RESERVATIONS_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT and the average max allocation.

```
WITH allocations AS
(SELECT
  AVG(res.slots_max_assigned) AS max_assigned,
  AVG(res.slots_assigned) AS slots_assigned,
FROM
 `my-slot-res-project.region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.RESERVATIONS_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT res
WHERE period_start BETWEEN 
   TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
   AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY
  reservation_id)
SELECT AVG(max_assigned) - SUM(slots_assigned) AS unallocated FROM allocations
```